# Composite fields in Birt

Tags: reporting, birt

I'm a total beginner with Birt (actually it's my first day with it) and my task is to create a Birt report that looks exactly like one done in Flash/Flex ... This report is looking really well.

The problem is: Im my Flex solution I have one field of a DataGrid that consists of a Label followed by a numeric output, if the numeric value is 0 or greater.

Based upon two values of a recordsets row I get an Internationalized Value by applying Mapping features of Birt (This allready works great). The resulting String should then be appended with "({value})" if value is greater or equal 0.

When using the designer, I can only place a second field in it's own table cell or table row, but I seem to be unable to output both fields in one table cell.

It would be great if someone could guide me through this.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build entire string in *Dynamic Text* JavaScript expession.

Using i18n in Javascript is briefly described in [BIRT FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Internationalization#Internationalization). The one interesting question could be [How can I localize strings in JavaScript](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Internationalization#Q%3a_How_can_I_localize_strings_in_Javascript.3F) - this expression gives localized text:

```
reportContext.getMessage("companyNameKey", reportContext.getLocale())
```

Row data is stored in the `row` array. All available fields you can find in an Expression Builder. As you found and double-clicked desired field, it appears expression like this:

```
row["FOO_NUMBER"].value
```

Putting all together:

```
reportContext.getMessage("Foo number:", reportContext.getLocale()) + 
  (row["FOO_NUMBER"].value > 0) ? ( "("+row["FOO_NUMBER"].value+")" ) : ("")
```

Comment: Hi ... thanks for that. It did the trick :-) ... As my "FOO_NUMBER" is of type Float, adding the value results in "undefined" being output. Leaving it away makes the dynamicText work as expected. The only thing left to solve it so make the float be output regarding the reports locale (Currently the float is output in the format "1.4", which is correct in the US, but in Germany it would have to be "1,4")

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jinowolskis post ... just wanted to add the full solution just if anyone runs into the same problem :-)

```
importPackage( Packages.java.text );
var myKey = "" + row["vulnerabilityClass"] + "." + row["result"];
if(row["cvssScore"] >= 0) {
    var nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(reportContext.getLocale());
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
    reportContext.getMessage(myKey, reportContext.getLocale()) + " (" + nf.format(row["cvssScore"]) + ")";
} else {
    reportContext.getMessage(myKey, reportContext.getLocale());
}
```